# Highlight <tr> if any value for <td> is different

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a Grails project and trying to highlight a table row if it does not have all matching records.

I want to highlight `<tr>` if its `<td>` doesn't match in that row. I am new to jQuery and getting difficulty in comparing `<td>` in same row.

```
$('table').on('mouseover', 'tr', function() {
   var textToMatch = $(this).text();
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JLubs/55/)

Line 1 and 4 should not highlighted, but its doing the opposite.

for example - first row has all numbers same as 7654321. So it is ok, but the second and third rows have different numbers in same row so they should be highlighted.

Comment: As far as I can see every row highlights when you hover on it. That's only because of the css rules you have defined. Your `.matching` class is supposed to style `tr`s, but you are applying it to your table instead.

Comment: Could you give a bit of clarification on when you want a `tr` to highlight? Do you only want them to highlight when you are hovering on them and all of the `td` elements do not match? Or are you trying to compare the td elements between rows?

Comment: ioums, i have updated question and code link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `isValid` will collect and compare all values in single row. If all values are the same it will return true, false otherwise.

```
$(function() {

    function isValid( $tr ) {
        return $tr
                .find( 'td' )
                .map( function() {
                    return $(this).text();
                })
                .get()
                .reduce( function(a, b) {
                    return ( a === b ) ? a : false; 
            }) !== false ; 
    }

    $('table').hover(
        function() {
            $( this ).find( 'tr' ).each( function() {
                if ( !isValid( $(this) ) ) $(this).addClass('matching');               
            });
        }, function() {          
            $( this ).find( 'tr' ).removeClass('matching'); 
        });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JLubs/58/)

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this is what you are looking for: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/733f7zcL/).

I changed your `textToMatch` so that it gets the text from the first `<td>`:

`var textToMatch = $(this).find('td:first').text();`

Then, instead of iterating over all of the `<tr>` elements I changed your code to iterate over the `<td>` elements in the row (`$(this).find('td').each` instead of `$('tr').each`).

Finally, I changed the text comparison to check that the text was different (`!==`) instead of the same (`===`) before adding the `matching` class. Note that since I am now iterating over the `<td>` elements `$(this).parent().addClass('matching')` is now applied to the `<tr>` instead of the `<table>`.

Comment: Looks like the above logic wont fit in real app scenario. only 1294 clientkey needs to highlight on load.jsfiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/733f7zcL/9/